# Qt in visual studio: connecting slots and signals doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots

I have installed Qt and Qt for VS plugin. Everything works fine, UI applications compile and run that's ok, but connecting signals and slots doesn't. I have `Q_OBJECT` in my class and for connecting I am using this code in constructor:

```
connect(ui.mainTableView, SIGNAL(activated(const QModelIndex &)),
        this, SLOT(showDetail(const QModelIndex &)));
```

EDIT:

showDetail method:

```
void MyClass::showDetail(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    this->setWindowTitle("it works");
}
```

window title is not changed and breakpoint is not reached.

moc files are generated in Generated Files directory, but moc file of that class is empty (others not), I think that it is because the class has no signal, but only one slot.

even connections generated by Designer don't work and the call of connect method returns `true`.

Comment: errors list should help. post it.

Comment: You should post your result as an answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: You should always check the return value of connect, usually with an assert. That way if it fails you'll know about it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESULT:

Oh no it turns out to be a silly question, thanks everybody, all answers pushed me towards the solution, but the last step was to find out that on my platform items are activated only by double-click, not single. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Remove variable names from `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros:

```
connect(ui.mainTableView, SIGNAL(activated(const QModelIndex &)),
    this, SLOT(showDetail(const QModelIndex &)));
```

For more details, read documentation on `QObject::connect` carefully.

Comment: Did you mark your `MyClass::showDetail` as slot in `MyClass` class definition?

Comment: Yes using `public slots: void showDetail(const QModelIndex &index);`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you got the `moc` working correctly? That would explain why the `connect` isn't doing its thing, but everything else is...

Comment: moc files are generated in `Generated Files` directory, but moc file of that class is empty (others not), I think that it is because the class has no signal, but only one slot.

Comment: moc_MyClass.cpp should not be empty even if you your class is empty, did you inherit `MyClass` from `QObject`?

Comment: Yes it inherits from QMainWindow. (It's really strange.)

Comment: Without `moc`-generated code, signals and slots won't work. Try to find out why `moc` generates empty file. Does `moc` display any warnings when processing your `MyClass.h`?

Comment: Have you tried copying all the code into a new project? I remember when I used to use Qt, I had lots of problems with QMake and the like, and sometimes it seemed like it just skipped over stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2012, when trying to use

```
connect(plot->xAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), plot->xAxis2, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));
```

I get errors for `plot` and `SIGNAL`.

This is because the incorrect connect was found by Visual Studio.  It found the `connect` in `winsock.h`.

To fix the errors, I used the `QObject` namespace as follows:

```
QObject::connect(plot->xAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), plot->xAxis2, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));
```

For reference, here is info on the errors.

For the first `plot` argument the error is:

```
ERROR: argument of type "QCPAxis*" is incompatible with parameter of type "Socket".
```

For the first `SIGNAL` the error is:

```
ERROR: argument of type "cosnt Char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "const sockaddr*".
```

For the second `plot` argument the error is:

```
ERROR: argument of type "QCPAxis*" is incompatible with parameter of type "int".
```

For the second `SIGNAL` the error is:

```
ERROR: too many arguments in function call.
```